# Emacs on Windows C-h and Shift-? issues

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am having some issues with Emacs 24 on Windows Vista. My Ctrl-H is somehow mapped to Backspace (not help-function). On the other hand, I can't type `?' (Shift-/ key). Is there a way to fix these two issues? Thank you very much.

EDIT: The emacs was downloaded directly from gnu website. It should be a windows native build.

Comment: I don't really know, but who someone who would, I think, these would matter: is it the Emacs installed from Cygwin, or is it a build you've downloaded from GNU site, or, perhaps built it yourself? These really sound like keyboard driver issues, so, maybe telling what kind of keyboard is that / have you tried another one would help too.

Comment: Try setting them manually, just as a data point (this shouldn't be used as a permanent fix); for example, `M-x global-set-key RET C-h k describe-key` and `M-x global-set-key RET ? self-insert-command`.  It may help to determine if something trickier is going on here.  The point @wvxvw raised is very important: where did you download your Emacs from?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are on Linux or UNIX.

1. Enter this at your Linux/UNIX shell prompt: `stty -a`.
2. Look at what follows `erase =` in the output.  It will be either `^H` or `^?`.
3. Depending on which it is, put that in your Linux/UNIX shell startup file (e.g. .cshrc, .bashrc) as the `stty erase` setting. IOW one of these:

   - `stty erase ^H`
   - `stty erase ^?`

Here is some more explanation:

- http://www.hypexr.org/linux_ruboff.php
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040930002324870
- http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/10766-ctrl-h-versus-versus-backspace.html
- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceKey